# Masonry Grid images sequential fade in

Tags: css, css-animations, jquery-masonry, image-gallery, masonry

I'm making a portfolio for my website and I'm using the Masonry grid. But I'm trying to make the images fade in when the page opens in sequential order. Something like on this website [Michael Molfetas](http://www.michaelmolfetas.com/). I tried using css transitions, I checked the Masonry documentation but I just can't make it work. I put together a quick [codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/aWZYGJ) with stock images I found on the web, but the format is pretty much how I want it.

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
         x.className += " responsive";
     } else {
         x.className = "topnav";
     }
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-icon3').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});

$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 250,
  isFitWidth: true
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

.header {
 background-color: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 7%;
 height: 80px;
}

h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 margin-top: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: #D18E8F;
}

#nav-icon {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 7%;
 margin-top: 8px;
 /*padding-right: 1%;*/
 float: right;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #8c8c8c;
 border-radius: 6px;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2), #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
 top: 10px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 20px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

.topnav {
  display: none;
}

.topnav.responsive {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 height: 160px;
}

ul.topnav.responsive {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
 float: left;
 margin-left: 7%;
 /*padding-left: 2%;*/
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 85%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
 padding-top: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a:hover {
 color: #7EBEA3;
}

.grid {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.grid-item img { 
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <title>Gabriella Farfan</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Gabriella Farfan</h1>
   <div id="nav-icon">
    <div id="nav-icon3">
     <a id="nav-icon3" onclick="myFunction();">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
     </a>
    </div> 
   </div>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
   </li>
   <li style="border-bottom: none">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_20912016.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/kotokomi/kotokomi1511/kotokomi151100206/48637357-Smiles-are-always-in-fashion-Inspirational-quote-handwritten-with-black-ink-and-brush-custom-letteri-Stock-Vector.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_52210298.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBlJjT5wpALRmHrOM3kLERHc01mw0GSDuMKheUGRCT2-rYN8_WfQ"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dihnACz_au0/UJlZxIsDIWI/AAAAAAAAGPE/F4u3xcep2e4/s1600/stock-illustrations-on-etsy.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_88472599.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9mly1dUwAAdTir.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.elliedujour.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2040070-1484093522-1.640x0c.jpg"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cute-cartoon-girl-vector-id528487686"></div>
 
</div>
  
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the images in masonry load in order to make a nice sequential animation, [codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/jmyjYx). The [ScrollReveal.js](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal) plugin helped achieve the effect.

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
         x.className += " responsive";
     } else {
         x.className = "topnav";
     }
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-icon3').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});

$('#grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 220,
  isFitWidth: true
});

// window.sr = ScrollReveal({ duration: 1000 });
// sr.reveal('.foo', 80);

window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.foo', { duration: 1000 }, 50);
```

```css
html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 1rem;
}

.header {
 background-color: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 7%;
 height: 80px;
}

h1 {
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-left: 1%;
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 margin-top: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: #D18E8F;
}

#nav-icon {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 7%;
 margin-top: 8px;
 /*padding-right: 1%;*/
 float: right;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #8c8c8c;
 border-radius: 6px;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2), #nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
 top: 10px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 20px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
 top: 10px;
 width: 0%;
 left: 50%;
}

.topnav {
  display: none;
}

.topnav.responsive {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 padding: 0;
 height: 160px;
}

ul.topnav.responsive {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
 float: left;
 margin-left: 7%;
 /*padding-left: 2%;*/
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 85%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
 padding-top: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a:hover {
 color: #7EBEA3;
}

#grid {
  overflow: hidden;
/*   box-sizing: border-box; */
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item img { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
/*   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s; */
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <title>Gabriella Farfan</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   </head>
   
   <body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Gabriella Farfan</h1>
   <div id="nav-icon">
    <div id="nav-icon3">
     <a id="nav-icon3" onclick="myFunction();">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
     </a>
    </div> 
   </div>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
   </li>
   <li style="border-bottom: none">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

   <div id="grid">
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_20912016.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/kotokomi/kotokomi1511/kotokomi151100206/48637357-Smiles-are-always-in-fashion-Inspirational-quote-handwritten-with-black-ink-and-brush-custom-letteri-Stock-Vector.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo"><div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_52210298.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBlJjT5wpALRmHrOM3kLERHc01mw0GSDuMKheUGRCT2-rYN8_WfQ"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dihnACz_au0/UJlZxIsDIWI/AAAAAAAAGPE/F4u3xcep2e4/s1600/stock-illustrations-on-etsy.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_88472599.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9mly1dUwAAdTir.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.elliedujour.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2040070-1484093522-1.640x0c.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cute-cartoon-girl-vector-id528487686"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_20912016.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/kotokomi/kotokomi1511/kotokomi151100206/48637357-Smiles-are-always-in-fashion-Inspirational-quote-handwritten-with-black-ink-and-brush-custom-letteri-Stock-Vector.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_52210298.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBlJjT5wpALRmHrOM3kLERHc01mw0GSDuMKheUGRCT2-rYN8_WfQ"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dihnACz_au0/UJlZxIsDIWI/AAAAAAAAGPE/F4u3xcep2e4/s1600/stock-illustrations-on-etsy.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/IllustrationsLanding/img_88472599.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C9mly1dUwAAdTir.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://www.elliedujour.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2040070-1484093522-1.640x0c.jpg"></div></div>
      <div class="foo">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cute-cartoon-girl-vector-id528487686"></div></div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to check if the image is loaded and then show it.

It's possible with [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) or [LazyLoad](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) plugins.

Simple example with imagesLoaded plugin:

CSS (add `opacity` and `transition` to images)

```
.grid-item img {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

Use imagesLoaded plugin (cdn https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js)

```
$(".grid").imagesLoaded()
  .progress(function(instance, image) {
    var $item = $(image.img);

    $item.css({
      "opacity": "1"
    });
  });
```

Fork of your code: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/lenevro/pen/oWYoKw?editors=0110)

With a slight random transition-delay effect: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/lenevro/pen/gWLyXZ?editors=0010)

With alerts :): [Codepen](http://codepen.io/lenevro/pen/RVoOoy)

--

I hope that is help you.

Comment: Thank you, I think your answer helped a little. I found a post that did the loading effect I wanted but includes a button to reveal images [link] (http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yogHI) I want to know how I can do the same but get rid of the button and the onclick function. I'm not very good at javascript.

Comment: You need just a similar transition effect for images, or load images when scroll down?

Comment: Both would be nice, I sort of managed to do the transition effect here https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/PmWWpm, but when I resize the window all the images float to the bottom

Comment: Thank you so much!